# Spring Boot Json Response being cut off

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

In my Spring Boot Backend running the embedded Tomcat, I've got an endpoint which does return quite some data from the database as JSON.

I've noticed that there is a request body limit around ~82000 characters. Meaning the body is just being cut off / trimmed and the client is getting invalid JSON as it's not properly terminated.

i.e. when using curl I'm getting:

`curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)`

Is there any configuration I can set to increase the limit? ~82000 characters isn't really much. It's *just* ~82kb.

Comment: Hi, maybe it's about the maxPostSize configuration on your tomcat ?

Comment: Alreay tried the following: ```server.max-http-header-size=8KB
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=2MB
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=2MB``` but no effect.

Comment: Can you modify directly the configuration of your tomcat ? Can you also try `spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB` in your `application.properties` (or more for testing purpose). Have you a logging system or something else that can show us the headers sent  (the goal is to sea the real size of your request with the header `Content-Type` (it is optional in HTTP 2 but some tools and frameworks still send it) ?

Comment: Adding that property didn't change anything. Here's  the curl output with `-v`: https://pastebin.com/kJ71cWgG

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @Vusual I've answered my own question with the fix that I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it ended up being an Nginx buffering issue that I was able to fix:

```
server {
  location /my-endpoint {
    # https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/tuning-proxy_buffer_size-in-nginx
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_buffers 4 1024k;
    proxy_buffer_size 512k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 1024k;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought you were out of thread. try using thread sleep in getting data.